# Gcov branch in vector::push_back function call

Tags: c++, code-coverage, stdvector, googletest, gcov

I am running gcov and for some reason it is creating a branch inside the function call vector::push_back. The gcov file looks like this:

```
       22:  374:    ret.push_back(min_idx);
call    0 returned 100%
branch  1 taken 100% (fallthrough)
branch  2 taken 0% (throw)
```

This is the result of unit tests of a "bigger" framework. When I make a simple example like this:

```
#include <vector>
int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    vec.push_back(6);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the gcov output:

```
        -:    0:Source:/home/rjohan69/work/test_proj/test_proj.cpp
        -:    0:Graph:test_proj.gcno
        -:    0:Data:test_proj.gcda
        -:    0:Runs:1
        -:    0:Programs:1
        -:    1:#include <vector>
        1:    2:int main() {
        2:    3:    std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        1:    4:    vec.push_back(6);
        3:    5:}
```

The bigger framework is compiled into a library. Could that be an issue? does that make it think the vector lib is a part of the bigger library? Or why does one create a branch inside the push_back function call and not the other?

Comment: that's likely the compiler optimizing things for your. You are only using compile time constants. In the other case adding to the vector might require it to reallocate.. (it's checking against capacity)

Comment: In general, `push_back` **may** branch to code that reallocates.  In your simple example, the compiler already knows if it must reallocate, so it doesn't need to generate runtime code to check.

Comment: I see, but then my question becomes: why would I want to test code/code coverage inside the standard lib? In general I guess I should mock libs but the std? If I don't figure out how to write tests that covers both branches I will never get perfect code coverage ( I know I am not supposed try to get 100% coverage but this feels wrong)